# To set a payment method for a shopping cart using soap Api in Android

Tags: soap, soap-api-v2, android

I am getting an error such

> SoapFault - faultcode: '1071' faultstring: 'Payment method data is empty.' faultactor: 'null' detail: null

Please could   anyone  help me

```
   SoapObject customerEntity1 = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"shoppingCartPaymentMethodEntity");
       // customerEntity1.addProperty("po_number","null");
        customerEntity1.addProperty("method","paypal_standard");
       // customerEntity1.addProperty("cc_cid","null");
       //customerEntity1.addProperty("cc_owner","null");
       //customerEntity1.addProperty("cc_number","null");
       // customerEntity1.addProperty("cc_type","null");

        request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartPaymentMethod");
        request.addProperty("sessionId", sessionId);
        request.addProperty("quoteId", quoteId);
        request.addProperty("paymentMethod", customerEntity1);
        request.addProperty("storeId",0);
        env.setOutputSoapObject(request);


        env.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
        Boolean customerAddressAdded1 = (Boolean) env.getResponse();



        Log.d("shoppingCartPayment", customerAddressAdded1.toString());
```

Comment: please check [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116728/validate-paypal-transaction-id-passed-by-android-in-site)

Answer (score 1):

Magento api is giving error because you are sending your Card details is null.
You have to send data in cart array.

```
$result = $proxy->shoppingCartPaymentMethod($sessionId, 10, array(
'po_number' => Purchase order number,
'method' => 'checkmo',
'cc_cid' => Credit card CID ,
'cc_owner' => Credit card owner ,
'cc_number' => Credit card number,
'cc_type' => Credit card type,
'cc_exp_year' => Credit card expiration year ,
'cc_exp_month' => Credit card expiration month 
));
```

Comment: In documentation it is given null

Comment: Thanks but method used in our case is paypal so its giving me again the same error

Comment: The Payment method that you're using must be in magento store as if you are using paypal then first you have to integrate paypal in your store then get payment list and after that send request

Comment: please check [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116728/validate-paypal-transaction-id-passed-by-android-in-site)